# Filters to apply for an application that can only run on IE compatibility

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode, webfiltering

I had to add filter classes to fix some vulnerabilities found in an application that can only run on Internet Explorer in the compatibility mode.

Post-deployment of the fixes, I am unable to see any of them being reflected in the application and the vulnerabilities are still present.

Is there any way I can know the reason why this is happening and whether it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

Tried adding the filter classes to fix the vulnerabilities.

Expected the vulnerabilities to be solved.

Comment: What kind of vulnerabilities are they? What the "filter classes" and how do you add it?
Is there any error message when running your application in Internet Explorer mode in Edge?
Please provide more detailed information to help us better understand the issue.